# Tout traitement ou tous traitements ?

Tags: tout-tous

Tout d'abord, si j'ai bien compris :

- tout traitement : chaque traitement
- tous traitements : n'importe quel traitement

Contexte : vaccinations, castrations ou applications de micropuces pour les chiens.
Donc tous les chiens n'ont pas besoin de tout faire, mais je sais pas si c'est la bonne logique à suivre....

Voici ma phrase :

*Pour effectuer **tout(s) traitement(s)** le plus rapidement possible, recherchez une clinique vétérinaire avant que votre chien n'arrive chez vous.*

Merci d'avance !!!

Comment: "Tou*s* traitements" est rarement utilisé. Plutôt, pour d'autres cas (exhaustivité : on mentionne tous les traitements possibles), avec l'article : "tous *les* traitements". Dans le cas que vous indiquez, "tou*t* traitement" est nettement préférable.

Answer (score 4):

Les deux sont corrects. J'aurais tendance à préférer le singulier :

> Pour effectuer tout traitement...

ou mieux :

> Pour effectuer toute intervention...

car un traitement est un soin médical qui a une certaine durée, ce qui n'est pas le cas des exemples donnés.

*Tout* peut aussi signifier *n'importe quel*, exemple :

> Tout corps plongé dans un liquide...

Comment: Merci ! J'ai rajouté les parenthèses juste pour montrer mon doute entre les deux versions :)

Comment: du coup "tout traitement" => n'importe lequel et "tous traitements" => chaque traitement ? (en fait le contraire de ce que j'avais écrit au début ?) Merci !

Comment: Il n'y a pas de différence fondamentale entre les deux.  Le pluriel a peut-être tendance à exclure le cas où un seul traitement concerne un chien donné. J'aurais d'ailleurs choisi *intervention* plutôt que *traitement*, aucun des trois exemples donnés n'étant à proprement parler un traitement.

Comment: J'aurais aussi tendance à préférer le singulier et j'ai l'impression que c'est la forme la plus utilisée, mais dur de trouver confirmation... J'ai l'impression qu'effectivement si on veut signifier "n'importe lequel/laquelle" on préférera le singulier : "Toute intervention doit être prévue à l'avance", tandis que pour désigner un ensemble on préférera le pluriel: "Toutes interventions considérées, j'ai bossé 80 heures cette semaine"

Comment: @jlliagre je suis d'accord que *traitement* ne marche pas pour une castrations ou application de micropuces, mais *intervention* serait peut-être trop pour une vaccination, n'est-ce pas ? Est-ce que *procédure* pourrait passer pour les trois cas ? Merci encore !

Comment: *Procédure* n'irait pas. Vacciner une personne ou un animal est aussi une intervention, certes pas chirurgicale mais on peut très bien utiliser ce mot ici.